# Inner Join apply condition to only one table

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Here is my query:

```
SELECT p.product_id,p.title,p.price,p.total_sales,p.total_revenue,p.timestamp,i.image_id
FROM products AS p
INNER JOIN products_images AS i
ON p.product_id = i.product_id
WHERE p.account_id = ? AND p.deleted=0 AND i.featured=1
```

I want to get `i.image_id WHERE i.featured = 1` but I don't know how to apply that condition so that it only applies to the images table. The query works but I don't get all my results from the products table, just one row.

Obviously in some cases there might not be an image_id available where featured=1. So it would have to spit out something else in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to

```
FROM products AS p
left outer join products_images AS i
ON p.product_id = i.product_id
AND i.featured=1
WHERE p.account_id = ? AND p.deleted=0"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN`, that way you'll get results even when there is no image. You'll get one line  for every image found. If it's not desirable, use `GROUP BY p.product_id` to get each product just once.

And yes, put the `AND i.featured=1` condition to ON statement, as @Abercrombieande mentioned.